# Need to get a line from a file onto queue and not the whole file text

Tags: java, file-io, queue

I'm having trouble properly getting one line of text at a time from a file onto a queue without taking the whole file into the queue. For example, I'd like only Write a program that reads a Java source file as an argument and produces an index of all identifiers in the file. For each identifier, print all lines in which it occurs. For simplicity, we will consider each string consisting only of letters, numbers, and underscores an identifier.
Declare a Scanner in for reading from the source file and call `in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9_]+")` Then each call to next returns an identifier.

```
public class Main { to get added to the queue but instead the whole file text is put into the queue instead of a line at a time. Sorry if my question is unclear


// Write a program that reads a Java source file as an argument and produces an index of all
// identifiers in the file. For each identifier, print all lines in which it occurs. For simplicity,
// we will consider each string consisting only of letters, numbers, and underscores an identifier.
// Declare a Scanner in for reading from the source file and call in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9_]+").
// Then each call to next returns an identifier.


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class E_15 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        // get scanner input from file
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File ("C:/Users/ramir/IdeaProjects/PA_7/src/Main.java"));
        Queue<String> test = new LinkedList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> phrase = new ArrayList<String>();

        /*
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(is);
        s.useDelimiter(delimiter);

        */

        // Iterates till end of file
        while (fileInput.hasNextLine())
        {
            // Here is the issue. Data will end up
            // containing the whole file instead of only that line
            String data = fileInput.nextLine();
            Scanner in = new Scanner(data);
            in.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z0-9_]+");

            // I believe around here or before is the issue that I'm having.
            // It adds all the file instead of only that line
            // Also trying to figure out how to display each line that it's displayed on
            // What the first one should look like for example
            // 0: public occurs in:
            // public class Main {
            //   public static void main(String[] args) {

            //System.out.println(data);
            test.add(data);


            while(in.hasNext())
            {
                // Getting each phrase/word into ArrayList
                String token = in.next();
                phrase.add(token);

         
            }
            in.close();
        }

        int index = 0;
        // This part works fine
        for(String num : phrase)
        {
            // printing the key
            System.out.println(index + ": " + num + " occurs in:");

            // printing the values

       
            // This to print out what
            for(String line : test)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println();
            ++index;
        }
    }
}

// Just java class get file front
// This is fine
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a_1 = 100;
        System.out.println(a_1);``
    }
}
```

I'd like it to only show `System.out.println(a_1)` because the line that's it's on [See This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu2Sw.png)
. I'm also have trouble printing it in all the lines that occur.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class ReadLineByLineExample2  
{  
public static void main(String args[])  
{  
try  
{  
//the file to be opened for reading  
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("Demo.txt");       
Scanner sc=new Scanner(fis);    //file to be scanned  
//returns true if there is another line to read  
while(sc.hasNextLine())  
{  
System.out.println(sc.nextLine());      //returns the line that was skipped  
}  
sc.close();     //closes the scanner  
}  
catch(IOException e)  
{  
e.printStackTrace();  
}  
}  
}
```

Try studying the above code. I hope it will help. Otherwise, you might need to open this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-file-line-by-line-in-java) for more detail.